# IOS In App Purchase error when downloading purchased item

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm developing an App with consumable In App Purchase; 99% of the time it works great but sometimes (for connection or server problems) when I will verify the receipt and then download some item (from my server) I get an error.

That's ok, it could happen but how can I resume download? 
When user try buy this item again, Apple shows the message "You've already purchased this In-App Purchase but it hasn't been downloaded" and this item doesn't works anymore. 
I save locally the receipt, so I could use it to resume my download (if user use the same device) but how can I tell Apple that the transaction was finish (Can I use                                         [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction] in this case? how?
)?

In other works, how can I avoid the "You've already purchased..." message?
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: i have the same behaviour. Have you find any solution?

Comment: No yet, I store the receipt an when user is online I try again. I think that it solution may be improved